# Disabling the calling of the two routes

Tags: laravel, routes

For my project, I need to have dynamic routes, because {slug} in URL can point to multiple resources.

```
/shoes - poinst to category
/black-slippers - points to product
```

Beside the wildcard route, I have also a few (50) static routes (all defined before wildcard route in routes/web.php)
But now, when is called static route, the wildcard route is performed also, e.g.:

```
Route::get('/profile', [\App\Http\Controllers\Frontend\UserProfileController::class, 'show'])->name('profile.show');
Route::get('{address}', [\App\Http\Controllers\Core\WebaddressController::class, 'resolveAddress'])->where('address', '.*');
```

In the browser is displayed Profile page (correctly), but in SQL Queries I see, that the query which is called in WebaddressController@resolveAddress is performed also.

If I comment wildcard Route, the query disappears.

What can I do to not perform wildcard route? Thanks

Please do not suggest changing the route style, I cant, this is the requested form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude some keywords from the wildcard route with regex in the `where` statement:

```php
Route::get(
    '{address}', 
    [\App\Http\Controllers\Core\WebaddressController::class, 'resolveAddress']
)
    ->where('address', '^(?!profile|other-static-route)$');
```

The list of keywords doesn't have to be hardcoded. You could create a list yourself, or parse keywords from the routes you defined, like this:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

$keywords = collect(Route::getRoutes())
    ->map(function ($route) {
        return Str::afterLast($route->uri(), '/');
    })
    ->filter(function ($keyword) {
        return !Str::endsWith($keyword, '}');
    })
    ->implode('|');
```

Add them to the where statement like this:

```php
->where('address', '^(?!' . $keywords . ')$');
```

Comment: Yea, I saw this in documentation. I hoped there will be some more elegant solution. With 50 static routes, the regex will be crazy :D

Comment: @Autista_z The list doesn't have to be hardcoded ;). See updated answer for a suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure is that a best practice, but you can make a custom middleware for:

```
Route::get('{address}', [\App\Http\Controllers\Core\WebaddressController::class, 'resolveAddress'])->where('address', '.*')
```

**->middleware('is_slug_route');**

And in your handle method of freshly created middleware you can check is provided url an actual slug.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
    $possibleSlug = $request->getPathInfo();
    if (Address::where('slug',$possibleSlug)->exists()) {
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Something like that

Comment: Actually, you can create a list of your static routes and compare with them without making queries for slugs.

Comment: Im trying to do that right now. But it looks like it is not working :(

Comment: Have you registered your middleware in Kernel.php?
project>app>http>kernel.php
In the end of $routeMiddleware array, like $routeMiddleware = [ 
...,
...,
'is_slug_route'=>\App\Http\Middleware\YourMiddleware
]

Comment: Yea. I solved it. Via middlewre is problem with order of Middlewares. But it shoul work too.

Comment: Good for you :)